# The volume of the material cut from the solid sphere $r^2+z^2 \le 9$ and the cylinder $r=3\sin{\theta}$

Tags: integration

What is the volume of the material cut from the solid sphere $r^2+z^2 \le 9$ and the cylinder $r=3\sin{\theta}$ ? My answer is two times of the standard answer so I am wondering whether I did it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

To make one full circle $r=3\sin(\theta)$, $\theta$  ranges between $0$ and $\pi$, if you extend $\theta$ more than this it will trace more than just one circle. It will start to trace were it already has traced. Think about what $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$ looks like.

[image]

Hence the we need to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3\sin(\theta)} \int_{-\sqrt{9-r^2}}^{\sqrt{9-r^2}} rdzdrd\theta$$

Comment: Thank you:) I agree with your answer, but the standard answer integrates z from 0 to sqrt(9-r^2). Maybe the standard answer is wrong?

Comment: Probably, or perhaps they bounded below by $xy$ plane.